# Strange problem when connecting to external host using PDO

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a big problem with my website. When I try to connect it to an external host, it gives me a strange error:

> Severity: error
>
> Exception: Call to a member function errorInfo()
> on bool
> /home/qtbflcqc/panel.unitchamp.ro/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php
>
> 295 Unable to connect to the database

When I try to connect to the database from my localhost, it works fine, without any problem.

So, when I try to place the website on my PC, and connect it to the external host, it works perfect , no problem, no errors, but when I try to connect to it from the website (which is hosted), it gives me that error.

I set the Remote Acces from the external host, so there should be no problems.

Here is my database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=188.x.x.x; dbname=name; charset=utf8;',
    'hostname' => '188.x.x.x',
    'username' => 'nameuser',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'name',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => 'application/cache/',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: You need to look at some logs to find out exacty what is failing, but obviously it is not connecting

Comment: What "logs" should I look to?

Comment: I would start with the MySQL logs

Comment: the only logs that I have are the one that I send in the topic. nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 'pconnect' => FALSE to 'pconnect' => TRUE.
Thanks